# Dynamically create SessionFactory in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

In my application, there are multiple databases for each client.I want to access database as per the client logged in my application.

There are two options for that:
1) Using multiple SessionFactory entry in hibernate-config.xml file.
2) Duplicate hibernate pojo file.

But I want to create LocalSessionFactoryBean,SessionFactory,TransactionManager all these at runtime. So how can I do this? **I don't want to do multiple entries of SessionFactory and DataSource in hibernate-config.xml File.**

I have tried below snippet.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceHibernateConfig
{

    private String  driverClassName;

    private String  url;

    String          hibernateDialect;

    boolean         hibernateShowSql;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean alertsSessionFactoryBean()
    {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(this.restDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.ezdi.cac.bean.table" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(this.hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource()
    {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(this.driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(this.url);
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        final HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(this.alertsSessionFactoryBean().getObject());

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslationPostProcessor()
    {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator()
    {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    final Properties hibernateProperties()
    {
        return new Properties()
        {
            {
                this.put("persistence.dialect", PersistenceHibernateConfig.this.hibernateDialect);
                this.put("hibernate.show_sql", PersistenceHibernateConfig.this.hibernateShowSql);
            }
        };

    }

    /**
     * @return the driverClassName
     */
    public String getDriverClassName()
    {
        return driverClassName;
    }

    /**
     * @param driverClassName the driverClassName to set
     */
    public void setDriverClassName(String driverClassName)
    {
        this.driverClassName = driverClassName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the url
     */
    public String getUrl()
    {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * @param url the url to set
     */
    public void setUrl(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    /**
     * @return the hibernateDialect
     */
    public String getHibernateDialect()
    {
        return hibernateDialect;
    }

    /**
     * @param hibernateDialect the hibernateDialect to set
     */
    public void setHibernateDialect(String hibernateDialect)
    {
        this.hibernateDialect = hibernateDialect;
    }

    /**
     * @return the hibernateShowSql
     */
    public boolean isHibernateShowSql()
    {
        return hibernateShowSql;
    }

    /**
     * @param hibernateShowSql the hibernateShowSql to set
     */
    public void setHibernateShowSql(boolean hibernateShowSql)
    {
        this.hibernateShowSql = hibernateShowSql;
    }

}
```

but whenever I get SessionFactory through LocalSessionFactoryBean and also through HibernateTransactionManager,I got it null.I don't know the reason why did I get null?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a Look at Hibernate Multi-Tenancy which is tailor made for this requirement. From Hibernate 4.x onwards it is available and advised to be used instead of using multiple `SessionFactory`. Please go through this [post](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html).

Answer (score 0):

All that follows only have sense in a web application, but as the question has spring-mvc tag ...

Assuming you have a way to get the database name from the connected username and do not access database until user is logged and session is established, you could simply put all the stuff in session scope.

Just add a scope annotation to relevant beans :

```
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

to use a JDP proxy provided you bind the bean through interface (should be the case at least for DataSource and SessionFactory, and also for the transaction manager if normaly used). If it breaks because you need to use classes, use `proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`.

That way, you can even bind the session factory in a (singleton bean) Dao, and thanks to scoped proxy, each user will use its own.

The delicate part is to write the `getUrl()` method, because it will have to return the correct url. But you can also use a session scoped bean to store the url and store the url at login time.